# How to control that all developers use the same library version?

Tags: javascript, angular, git, github, npm

We develop in Angular with Visual Studio Code using GitHub as a code repository. This works fine, but recently we had a problem due to one of the developers having a different version of a certain library. Since installing with `npm` doesn't require to specify the version (it installs the latest) he ended up with a version different from the other developers.

One way to solve the problem is to put all the libraries in GitHub, but that seems overwhelming. What are the best practices to have all developers use the same version of javascript libraries?

Comment: I guess I may be misinformed, but isn't that the role of package-lock? Is the file committed in the repo?

Comment: 1) Designate fixed versions of Angular in your `package.json` (e.g.  `"8.0.0"`) or 2) If you want to stick with SemVer specs to update minor and patch versions (e.g. `"^8.0.0"`), commit your `package-lock.json` file.

Comment: it's a good question. You can require exact versions in your package.json using @.

Comment: yeah I aggree with @miqh, you need the package-lock.json so that, when one member uses npm-install. The library should install the right version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `package.json` specifies the version of dependencies and that you commit this file

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "foo": "1.2.3"  exact version
    "bar": ">1.2.3" greater than 1.2.3
    "baz": "^1.2.3" compatible with 1.2.3, ie from 1.2.3 until below 2.0.0
  }
}
```

[More details on semantic versionning](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies)

`package.json` defines which range of versions can be installed, but `package-lock.json` defines which *exact versions of all packages* (all = includes dependencies of dependencies) are installed. You have to commit this file.

Also, prefer `npm clean-install` rather than `npm install` because it throws an error if the installed packages in the node modules folder don't match the ones defined in the package lock.

Comment: I prefer to use `package-lock.json` so everybody has the same library versions, even small changes can make a difference.